# how to use the sample of android-sdk-windows\extras\android\compatibility\v4

Tags: android

I want to test the sample of android-sdk-windows\extras\android\compatibility\v4 in the sdk1.6 +. In the eclipse, I want to import the sample, but the app shows mistakes. I also added the jar to the sample, but it also shows mistakes. Can you tell me how to import the sample to the eclipe?

Comment: Please describe your problem. What sort of errors do you get?

Answer (score 3):

If importing the sample fails,Try creating new project from existing source option.

File->New->Android project => check create from existing source